# ldapadd fails with error: Inappropriate authentication (48)

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, centos7, ldap-query

I'm trying to add an organization with ldapadd command and I keep getting Inappropriate authentication (48) error.

My command -

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Directory Administrators,dc=mit,dc=example,dc=com" -W  -f my_org.ldif
```

This is what I get -

```
Enter LDAP Password: 

ldap_bind: Inappropriate authentication (48)
```

This is my ldif file - my_org.ldif

dn: cn=em,dc=mit,dc=example,dc=com

ou: em

objectClass: top

objectclass: organizationalunit

This is my output for

```
 ldapsearch -x -w -D 'cn=Directory Administrators,dc=mit,dc=example,dc=com' -b 'dc=mit,dc=example,dc=com' '(objectclass=*)'

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=mit,dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=Directory Administrators,dc=mit,dc=example,dc=com
# requesting: (objectclass=*) 
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That specific error code is returned by servers, when the method to authenticate is supported by the server but it doesn't have the appropriate level of security to proceed.

LDAP simple bind on a plain LDAP connection transfer passwords in clear and that is a serious security risk.

When authenticating with a directory server with a simple bind, you should do it on a secured connection. Either on LDAPS or after using StartTLS.